# Clojure - calculating a value for a map key

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of maps. Each map has three keys :x, :y and :z. I want that the value of :z would be the sum of the values of keys :x and :y. How should I do this? i.e.

```
[{x: 5 :y 10 :z (+ :x :y)} {...} {...}]
```

In the above example, the first map's :z value should then be (+ 5 10) = 15.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to parameterize this logic by extracting it out into a function if you plan on repeatedly doing this, although I would just create the `:z` key at the time you create the map, since you will presumably have access to `x` and `y` at that time.

Barring that, here is an alterative to the fine solutions presented already, just generalized for different arguments.

```
(def ms  [{:x 5 :y 10} {:x 5 :y 12} {:x 8 :y 10}])

(defn assoc-from-existing [m k & ks]
  (assoc m k (->> (select-keys m ks) vals (apply +))))

(mapv #(assoc-from-existing % :z :x :y) ms)
```

Comment: If you are already doing generalization then you could also pass function which is applied to vals as argument:
(defn assoc-from-existing [f m k & ks]
  (assoc m k (->> (select-keys m ks) vals (apply f))))

Comment: Absolutely, I should have added that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add those keys afterwards, you have to look at how to manipulate maps.  In this case e.g. Destructuring and `assoc` are fine:

```
user=> (def m {:x 42 :y 666})
#'user/m
user=> (let [{:keys [x y]} m] (assoc m :z (+ x y)))
{:x 42, :y 666, :z 708}
```

Or if you want to create new maps with just the coords write a function for that

```
user=> (defn coord [x y] {:x x :y y :z (+ x y)})
#'user/coord
user=> (coord 42 666)
{:x 42, :y 666, :z 708}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can call [assoc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc) to set a value under a key in a map. Note that most Clojure data structures are [immutable](https://clojure.org/about/functional_programming#_immutable_data_structures) so you can not alter the existing values but create modified copies.
- You can call [map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) or [mapv](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) functions or the [for macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) to iterate over a collection. `map` and `for` will return a lazy sequence and `mapv` will return a vector.

A simple solution:

```
;; first we define the data
(def ms [{x: 5 :y 10} {:x 1 :y 1} {:x 2 :y 3}])

;; then we define a function that creates mutated data
(defn add-sum [ms] (mapv (fn [m] (assoc m :z (+ (:x m) (:y m)))) ms))
```

Alternatively with `for` macro:

```
(defn add-sum [ms] (for [m ms] (assoc m :z (+ (:x m) (:y m)))))
```

Or with [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring):

```
(defn add-sum [ms] (for [{:keys [x y]} ms] (assoc m :z (+ x y))))
```